# junit5 how run all classes in test folder?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, junit5, suite

[image]

How i run all Test Class in src/test/java/* from Executor?

```
package it.anas.testSuite;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class Executor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore.main("./src/test/java/SmartRoadSimulator");
    }

}
```

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: Production code executing the test code of the same module seems strange to me. Not to mention you're targeting the test _source_ directory. Test code needs to be compiled before it can be executed. What are you actually trying to do? What's wrong with using `mvn test`?

Comment: class Test are simple test on Rest Service GET/POST.

Comment: Well, `src/test/java` is supposed to unit test the production code in `src/main/java` and the latter should be completely unaware of the former. Also, you mention JUnit 5 in both your question title and the question tags but `import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` indicates JUnit 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project and **`run as -> junit`** 
this will run the all test class files in your **src/test/java**

Comment: In my case i'm using STS and springboot application there is a skip test check box i click that one and run to run main main method only.